# Wizardry 8 saved game editor/trainer/cheat engine

Tags: windows, gratis, editor, gaming

Does anyone know of a saved game editor/trainer/cheat engine for [*Wizardry 8*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wizardry_8)?

Nice to have:

- Change character stats/level/HP, skills.
- Add spells.
- "Clipping" - walk through walls, or change party position.

Must have:

- Add items to inventory.
- Must work with [the GOG.com version](https://www.gog.com/game/wizardry_8).

Please don't just Google - I am doing that - only post something that you know to work and have actually used.

Comment: just had the usual S.E experience - a downvote with no explanation. And @Joel and @Jeff try to tell us that these are educational sites; that we are supposed to explain things, an help others to understand `</rant>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, if this question is on topic, then [this page](http://www.zimlab.com/wizardry/recovered/samjack/), has [this editor](http://www.zimlab.com/wizardry/recovered/samjack/wizedit.zip) which does exactly what I want